# Regex : ignoring particular string or skip/look ahead certain bracket

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am using this regex to match and extract information from a log line:

```
^([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\):\s([\w]+)\s([^:]*):\s(.*)\s\[([^\]]+)\]$
```

It works as expected for

> P:\Application\PativeCommon\Cws2essel.h(50): warning C26812: The enum
> type 'Cws2essel::eVesselSource' is unscoped. Prefer 'enum class' over
> 'enum' (Enum.3). [P:\PativeFunctionLib.vcxproj]

But fails due to the (x86) in the following line

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
> VisualStudio\2021\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\xmemory(702,82):
> warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to '_Objty',
> possible loss of data
> [G:\agent_work\48\s\Application\FunctionLib.vcxproj]

This is my code:

```
let rx = /^([^(]+)\(([^)]+)\):\s([\w]+)\s([^:]*):\s(.*)\s\[([^\]]+)\]/
let [, codeFile, codeLine, severity, ruleId, message, project] = logLine.match(rx);
```

regex101 Link: https://regex101.com/r/n5kG86/1

What modifications do I need to parse the line with `(x86)` too.
Is there a way to ignore this particular string or maybe look ahead and match the `()` closest to `:`

Please feel free to suggest better/more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```sh
^(.+?)\((\d[\d,]*)\):\s(\w+)\s([^:]*):\s(.*)\s\[([^\]]+)\]$
```

[Updated Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n5kG86/2)

Important changes are in first 2 capture groups:

- `^`: Start
- `(.+?)`: First capture group to match a string with 1 or more of any characters (lazy match)
- `\(`: Match opening `(`
- `(\d[\d,]*)`: 2nd capture group to match a string starting with a digit followed by 0 or more digit/comma characters
- `\)`: Match closing `)`